# call model function from attr in knockout js to get dynamic attributes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, attr

I am not so fluent in knockout js, so this could be a silly one.

my model looks like this:

```
  var myViewModel = {
    personName: 'Bob',
    attributesAttached: 'title:SampleTitle',
    getTitle : function(){
    return "SampleTitle";
    },
    getAttributeKeyValuePair : function(){
       return "title : SampleTitle";
    },
     getAttributeKeyValuePairCollection : function(){
       return "title : SampleTitle , href : test.html";
    }

    };

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

My **Working** html looks like this :

```
The name is
<span data-bind="text: personName,attr: { title :  getTitle() }"></span>
```

**I want to achieve this :**

**not working**

```
The name is
<span data-bind="text: personName,attr: { getAttributeKeyValuePair() }"></span>
```

Because later on some property or method would give me a collection of attribute key value pairs

**not working**

```
The name is
<span data-bind="text: personName,attr: { getAttributeKeyValuePairCollection() }"></span>
```

How can i make that work so that i can have my attribute names and their respective values generated dynamically(as and when my JSON is fully processed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attr` binding-handler is expecting an object, where each property-name is correspondent to the attribute name, and the property-value to the attribute value.

So your `getAttributeKeyValuePairCollection()` method simply needs to return object:

```
getAttributeKeyValuePairCollection: function() {
   return {
          href: 'test.html',
          title: 'SimpleTitle'
          };
}
```

And in your `data-bind`:

```
<span data-bind="text: personName, attr: getAttributeKeyValuePairCollection()"></span>
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html)

Comment: i think i gave up too early on experimenting with the syntax. my bad. thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

you did not specify an attribute you want to set

i dont know which attribute you want to set but the syntax would be:

```
  data-bind="attr:{'class': getAttributeKeyValuePair()}"
```

this would result in

```
  <span class="title : SampleTitle" >
```